# Does the extra damage of a Flame Tongue sword work with an attack made as part of the Booming Blade cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, damage, cantrips

I'm planning a magic initiate Rogue with the *Booming Blade* Cantrip. He will have a Flame Tongue as it is a higher level character. I already know that Booming Blade and Sneak Attack work together but what I'm unsure of is if the extra damage from the Flame Tongue would work as well.

Example is at 5th level *Booming Blade* adds 1d8 Thunder damage to the normal attack and the Flame Tongue adds 2d6 Fire damage, so if I use a Rapier I would get 1d8 Piercing + 1d8 Thunder + 2d6 Fire + 3d6 Sneak attack (assuming I qualify for sneak attack) + Mod. I'm not concerned with the secondary damage from the target moving. This attack would average (with everything factored) 30.5 damage with a modifier of 4, average 57 with a crit. Would this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

The relevant line from the description of *booming blade*:

> On a hit, the target suffers the [the melee attack with a weapon]'s normal effects, and [...]
>
> --- *Sword Coast Adventure's Guide*, p. 143

Such additional effects include Sneak Attack<sup>1</sup> and that additional damage from Flame Tongue as that effect is:

> While the sword is ablaze, it deals an extra 2d6 fire damage to any target it hits.
>
> --- *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 170

---

1: Assuming the melee weapon you use has finesse such that it works with Sneak Attack. Flame Tongue can be "any sword" so there are such versions possible.